# Java program not working after building giving Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven, javafx, package

I have a problem that when I try to run the program I made it does nothing and when I try to run it in cmd using
`java <programName.jar>`
it gives me this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class GymBase-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GymBase-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar
```

I made the jar using  `mvn install` from maven for javaFX using shade plugin, I already edited the pom.xml file to try to solve it by correcting the main class, I have a repo for the project on my github : https://github.com/T1t4n25/GymBase

Comment: It should be `java  -jar <programName.jar>` and you also need a main class defined in the jar and meta inf plus execution is different of [a shaded jar including JavaFX components is not supported, though you might get it to work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing).

Comment: In the duplink 1st answer, look for "Alternative syntaxes for java" which explains (among other things) how to execute a JAR file.

Comment: is there a better and simpler way to package my application for the user to use it without going for technical stuff

Comment: You can use jpackage, it is simpler for the user but more difficult for you the developer.  Alternately, you can use jlink via the [maven-javafx-plugin](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxjlink-options) to create a zipped image, as long as your app and all its dependencies are fully modular.  That is easy for you and easy enough for the customer, (they unzip the distribution and run the bundled shell script).  It will only work on one target OS/architecture, unless you build on multiple machines, but that might be OK depending on app and userbase.

Comment: I tried the method @jewelsea mentioned but the shell command didn't launch the program as the tutorial mentioned